# How do I display both 'individual' and 'team' plans to a user registering?

Tags: laravel, laravel-spark

How do I display both 'individual' and 'team' plans to a user registering? My app requires 1 x paid team plan, and 2 x paid individual plans.

In my `SparkServiceProvider` if I comment out the individual plans, the team plan shows up on the registration form, along with an input for the user's team name. However if I include the individual plans in the service provider, the team plan is hidden.

```
public function booted()
    {
        Spark::useStripe();
        // Spark::chargePerTeam();
        Spark::billsTeams();
        Spark::details([
            'some' => 'information'
        ]);

        Cashier::useCurrency('gbp', '£');

        Spark::useRoles([
            'member' => 'Member',
            'vip' => 'VIP',
        ]);

        Spark::teamPlan('Institution', 'institution-plan')
        ->price(350)
        ->yearly()
        ->maxTeams(1)
        ->maxTeamMembers(4)
        ->features([
            'Full access to member forums',
            'Up to 4 profile pages for your team users',
            'All team members have the same access'
        ]);

        Spark::plan('Independent', 'plan_FFQgFP56Vtj3vt')
            ->price(75)
            ->yearly()
            ->maxTeams(0)
            ->features([
                'Full access to member forums',
                'Profile page',
            ]);

        Spark::plan('Affiliated', 'independent-plan')
            ->price(125)
            ->yearly()
            ->maxTeams(0)
            ->features([
                'Full access to member forums',
                'Profile page',
                'For employed individuals whose organisation pays the fee'
            ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a response from Mohamed Said of Laravel:

“We don't support that out of the box, if there are user plans then these are the plans that appear on signup since the one signing up is a "User".”

So I am going to try roll out my own registration component and conditionally show a team name field if a team plan is selected. I will report back my findings.